# What's the difference between 呪術【じゅじゅつ】, 魔法【まほう】, 奇術【きじゅつ】, and 魔術【まじゅつ】?

Tags: word-choice, words

Is there any difference between these nouns?

Is this like the difference between 'magic' and 'sorcery' in English?

Is 魔法【まほう】 used most often?

Comment: May want to include 魔術 as well.

Comment: [妙技【マジック】](http://imgur.com/bmIL9yC)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**奇術【きじゅつ】**: Illusion or stage magic, which has tricks and is performed by real magicians all over the world. A person who does this is called マジシャン or 奇術師. But in this sense, the most common word is katakana マジック. Table magic is often called 手品【てじな】, too.

**魔法【まほう】**: Supernatural kind of magic. Typical 魔法 is what you can find in *Harry Potter* franchise or various fantasy role-playing games. Basically used only in fictions.

**呪術【じゅじゅつ】**: Ritual magic, performed by real people in order to [invoke rain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainmaking_(ritual)), curse someone, etc. It frequently appears in serious anthropological contexts, but it's used in fictions, too.

**魔術【まじゅつ】**: This is similar to 魔法, but is an ambiguous word which can refer to everything above. Many sport players are nicknamed ～の魔術師.